# Submitting and filling form without an ID in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms

A while ago on an old weebly site of mine (before i had javascript knowledge) i searched for a way to go to a page only i know about and log into weebly automatically.

i came accross the code below that worked (slightly modified) with what i needed.

```
<form id="formID" target="frame" method="post" action="[posturl]">
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="__" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="__" />
</form>

<iframe id="frame" name="frame" width="800" height="350"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
// submit the form into iframe for login into remote site
document.getElementById('formID').submit();

// once you're logged in, change the source url (if needed)
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
*/iframe.onload = function() {
    if (iframe.src != "") {
        iframe.src = "";
    }
}/*
</script>
```

Now i need to use it for another website, the problem being that it needs a form Id, which the target page/form doesn't have.

Here's what the form code on the target page looks like:

```
<form action="[posturl]" method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" class="ssi_table">
<tr>
<td align="left" width="85"><label for="user"><b>Username:</b></label>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" size="9" value="" class="input_text"/></td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left"><label for="passwrd"><b>Password:</b></label>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="password" name="passwrd" id="passwrd" size="9" class="input_password"/></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="cookielength" value="-1"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<center><input type="submit" value="Login" value="Login" class="button_submit"/></center>
</form>
```

My main question is, is there any way to identify and submit the form without the need for an ID, and how would I fill the form without an ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `document.forms[.. index ..]`. For instance if it is the first form in the document it would be

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

I see you have other fields in your form. You could also navigate *up* to the form.